# Pthreads becoming slow on iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, pthreads, voip

I have around 4 pthreads created of default priority and default scheduling in my iOS VOIP application. After around 50-60 VoIP calls, i noticed one of my pThreads becoming very slow and preempted for a long time (around 500+ milli seconds). Does any one have any insight to this sort of an issue ?

Can this be due to Over consumption of memory by the app ? If so why only is one thread sufferring.  Any suggestions ?

All operations are happening while App is in the Foreground

Thanks,
~Titus

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at libdispatch...

Comment: This is done in C/C++ layer for iOS. GCD are used in objective C layer.

Comment: GCD is actually a C API.